# Where can I find a list of exit codes and their meanings for the PowerShell ServerManager cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, servermanager

I'm using the PowerShell ServerManager cmdlet and haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of exit codes for the installation commands.

```
$feature = Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core
exit $feature.ExitCode
```

What values can I expect ExitCode to contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used this cmdlet, but based on @vmrob's initial answer, it appears that `ExitCode` is in instance of the `Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureOperationExitCode` enum type.

You should be able to get a list of possible values like this:

```
[enum]::GetNames( [Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureOperationExitCode] )
```

Comment: I actually answered my own question there and was looking for a much better way of finding these things. I'm still new to PowerShell and this looks like it answers a different question that I didn't know how to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the current version of the PowerShell cmdlets act as a wrapper around the deprecated `servermanagercmd.exe`. If this is the case, then the exit codes listed here should be applicable:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733119.aspx

The exit codes that I've encountered so far match:

#### With a feature that is already installed

```
PS C:\> $feature = Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core
PS C:\> $feature.ExitCode
NoChangeNeeded
PS C:\> $feature.ExitCode.value__
1003
```

#### When a feature fails to install due to a needed restart

This can happen after Windows Update runs but before the computer is restarted.

```
PS C:\> $feature = Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core
PS C:\> $feature.ExitCode
FailedRestartRequired
PS C:\> $feature.ExitCode.value__
1001
```

#### On success

```
PS C:\> $feature = Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core
PS C:\> $feature.ExitCode
Success
PS C:\> $feature.ExitCode.value__
0
```